# How to mask multiple Docker containers to a single public IP on Windows 10/ Server 2016

Tags: windows, docker

We need to run multiple containers (For scaling) on a single IP which should be a public IP and can be accessed from anywhere.

Tried mapping Host IP-Port to container port but each container is to be mapped to a different port - Hence, not what we were looking for.

Natting was an option (Creating container with same IP as previous one) but in that case we needed to stop and delete previous container - Causing serious down time. - Not acceptable.

Comment: Are you talking about load balancing?

Comment: It almost sounds like you're describing what you get if you use the 'docker service' interface that is a part of swarmkit. You can create a single service, and scale it out to n replicas. A published port on a service gets put behind the "routing mesh" feature, and docker sets up a vip internally and passes requests to each container backing the service in a round-robin fashion.

Comment: @Rao No, i am not asking about load balancing, I am looking for upgrade of existing containers with Zero or minimal down time while keeping the end user access (In my case a static host IP) point same.

Comment: @programmerq If you are talking about creating an overlay network then it didn't solve my problem.
Scaling of the service created containers with different IP's so how are my requests going to be redirected?
I am new to this so can you please elaborate about how i can achieve my end result.